# JPA with JTA is having class loader issues

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using JPA 2.0, eclipselink 2.x and maven. This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="certifications" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/com/ni/ds_edata_soa_nontx</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliCertificationStg</class>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliCertificationStgPK</class>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliUpMapping</class>   
        <properties>                        
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ni"/>
            <!--property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="NI"/-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>       
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have this AbstractFacade

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "certifications")
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Gets the entity manager
     * @return
     */
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        if(emf == null){
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("certifications");
        }
        if(em == null){
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
        }
        return em;
    }

}
```

And this is how I implement it

```
public class CertificationFacade extends AbstractFacade{

    /**
     * Gets the certifications for the paramenter upId
     * @param upId the upId
     * @return the certifications
     * @throws CertificationException
     */
    public List<NicdsCliCertificationStg> getCertificationsByUpId(String upId)
            throws CertificationException {
        String stringQuery = new StringBuilder(
                "select c from NicdsCliCertificationStg c, NicdsCliUpMapping d where c.id.contactsId = d.contactsId and d.profileId =")
                .append(upId).toString();
        try {
            TypedQuery<NicdsCliCertificationStg> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(stringQuery,
                    NicdsCliCertificationStg.class);            
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CertificationException(
                    CertificationConstants.INTERNAL_ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the DAO

```
    public final class CertificationDAO {

    private CertificationDAO(){}

    /**
     **Gets the certifications for the requested upId
     * @param upId the upId
     * @return the certifications
     * @throws CertificationException
     */
    public static Certifications getCertificationByUpId(String upId) throws CertificationException{
        Certifications response = new Certifications();
        List<NicdsCliCertificationStg> certifications = new CertificationFacade().getCertificationsByUpId(upId);
        CertificationType newCertification = new CertificationType();
        for(NicdsCliCertificationStg cert : certifications){
            newCertification.setAlternateEmail(cert.getAlternateEmail());
            newCertification.setCertificationName(cert.getId().getCertName());
            newCertification.setContactId((int)cert.getId().getContactsId());
            newCertification.setFirstName(cert.getFirstName());
            newCertification.setLastName(cert.getLastName());
            newCertification.setPrimaryEmail(cert.getPrimaryEmail());
            newCertification.setStatus(cert.getCertStatus());
            response.getCertification().add(newCertification);
        }
        return response;        
    }
}
```

The exception is caused when I try to iterate through the list. I get a ClassCastException. I've been reading, and this is caused by 2 possible reasons: 1) the class is duplicated in the classpath (which is not so in my case) and 2) there are 2 different classloaders at the same time. This exception also happens when I redeploy the app to my weblogic. It seems that the garbage collector doesn't recycle the old classloader fast enough, and when I run the app, I'm dealing with two classloaders at the same time, causing the classcast exception. What I don't understand is that since I'm using JTA transaction type in my persistence.xml, the lifecycle of the EntityManagerFactory should be handled automatically. One option would be to close the factory myself, but I'm more interested in learning why isn't the JTA handling this for me. Thanks!

--EDIT--
Stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliCertificationStg
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.dao.CertificationDAO.getCertificationByUpId(CertificationDAO.java:25)
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.rest.implementation.CertificationService.getCertificationByUpId(CertificationService.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1382)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:717)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.filter.ConfigurableRepRestServletFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableRepRestServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace, also the CertificationFacade code is duplicated in the post... it is missing the Dao code

Comment: Oops, sorry, just noticed. On it.

Comment: It looks weird, did you debug this code.. does this error happen if it is not deployed in the weblogic? I mean did you try to run this piece of code using a basic java main? I suggest you doing that to reduce the error scope

Comment: The whole app is deployed to my customer's weblogic, and I don't have access to the database. If I do emf.close() after running the query, it all works, but as you said, it is pretty weird.

Comment: the answer is simple, if you dont do the emf.close() the EMF will never be closed, and in the next request a new one will be created because you create a new instance of the CertificationFacade class... if you need some class to help with the lifecycle of the EntityManagerFactory, use the OpenSessionInViewFilter filter

Comment: But does it make sense even if the EMF is static?

Comment: Sorry... I missed the static field, so you will need to bind it.. try to add the code `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(emf, new EntityManagerHolder(em));` after you create the entityManager, anyway I still suggest you to use the OpenSessonInViewFilter... this piece of code was extacted from there

Comment: Hmm... It looks pretty cool, but I can't use Spring. My customer, for some reason, thinks it's too complicated to integrate it because of existing frameworks. I appreciate your help. If you have any other ideas, they're more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is how I fixed it.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.controller.AbstractFacade;

public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        AbstractFacade.closeFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

That way, everytime I redeploy the app, I make sure that the factory that I've created is closed.

-Edit-
Just to make it clear, after creating that Listener class, I have to add the listener to the web.xml like this

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.filter.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The closeFactory() simply does emf.close() after verifying that emf is not null.